# Get lines of a UI text in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use the following code to get everyline of a text that I have in Text. but the code does not return the lines that are showing in the game, it returns what I have entered in inspector.

```
myText = GetComponent<Text>();
string[] lines = myText.text.Split('\n');
try{print(lines[0]);}catch{}
try{print(lines[1]);}catch{}

//real output :
//New Text
//What I expect:
//New
//Text
```

There is a picture :
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEzId.png)

How can I get lines that are in the game window?

This is my first post, so excuse any mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is **displayed** as two lines because of the the [`Text.horizontalOverflow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-horizontalOverflow.html) property of the `Text` component is set to `Wrap`, but that not means it has been changed to two lines like "New \nText". It is still "New Text".

[image]

If you set `horizontalOverflow` to `Wrap`, `Text` will word-wrap when reaching the horizontal boundary. So the output becomes two lines in your case.

You need to set it to `Overflow` so the text can exceed the horizontal boundary. Then the text will not be influenced by the border of the text `GameObject`.

Comment: I'm not looking for the reason this happens. I want to gain access to lines that are shown in game windows. Actually I want to generate Text in Runtime and put it in Text and change the order of lines. for example I want to move the first line of text to the last line .

Comment: Just set `horizontalOverflow` to `Overflow` and do what you want. You can set the text back by `myText.text = "Generated text in runtime"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same text, the problem is that the width of the RectTransform of the Text Object is too small, increase the width or decrease the text size.